# FeedMe plugin broke Craft

Tags: php, plugin-feedme

I was using the FeedMe plugin engram-design to move my podcast xml items to entries in a podcast section I tried running a task to update some entries and it broke my site. Now I am unable to access the admin portion of my site. I receive the following error.

`Fatal error: Class 'Craft\FeedMe_FeedModel' not found in /www/sites/mywebsite/craft/app/helpers/ModelHelper.php on line 587`

I've tried replacing the app folder with a fresh copy, but nothing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a FeedMe file more than a Craft one.  Try downloading a fresh copy of the plugin and swapping it out?

Comment: Just tried that..still no good. When I ran the task to move items to entries I ran it a few times not realizing it was already running. It seemed like it "timed out" or something.

Answer (score 3):

You'll be able to get better/quicker help through the plugin page and submitting an issue - https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe/issues. I'd be happy to help and see what might be the issue.

But if you could, please follow the Support steps as outlined here - https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe#support.